# Problems running python script from motion

Tags: scripting, python, raspberry-pi, motion

I'm trying to set up the raspberry pi with my webcam as a motion detecting cctv that uploads the videos to google drive using [Jeremy Blythe's script](http://jeremyblythe.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/motion-google-drive-uploader-and.html)

I have motion working correctly and the python script runs when I test it from the terminal.

However the script doesn't run when I add it to the on_movie_end option in motion.conf.

The script I am using in the file is

```
On_Movie_End /etc/motion/uploader.py /etc/motion/uploader.cfg %f
```

I have also tried getting the on_movie_end to run a bash script that runs the python script and this doesn't work either. I am new to linux though so not entirely sure I have it correct.

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
VIDEO=$1 
/etc/motion/uploader.py /etc/motion/uploader.cfg VIDEO
```

In motion.conf
   /etc/motion/uploaderscript.sh %f

Comment: Perhaps you should do `/usr/bin/python 
/etc/motion/uploader.py /etc/motion/uploader.cfg VIDEO`.  Or check if python binary is installed in other directory and change the above line.

Comment: in bash you should have to use variable as `/etc/motion/uploader.py /etc/motion/uploader.cfg $VIDEO`

Comment: neither of those solutions work but I suspect the on_movie_end is not being called as I tried to get it to just open leafpad to see if that was working and it didn't

Answer (score 1):

Check the following points:

1. All the examples I saw use `on_movie_end` instead of `On_Movie_End`. So try using the lowercase version first.
2. Check if both script have execution permission. If not add it:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/motion/uploader.py
   sudo chmod +x /etc/motion/uploaderscript.sh
   ```
3. Redirect the stderr of the python script to a file. That can help to catch a error. Edit the .sh file to match this (note the `$VIDEO`: it is the correct way to reference a variable in bash):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   VIDEO=$1 
   /etc/motion/uploader.py /etc/motion/uploader.cfg $VIDEO &> /tmp/on_movie_end.log
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't been able to figure out how to play a python script from motion. Instead, I just run a bash script which creates a text file. On start-up, I have the actual python script running a while loop, checking to see if the text file exists, and will run the rest of the script once it does.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works for me:

```
on_movie_end /usr/bin/python /home/myuser/Scripts/MyScript.py
```

Of course, the script must have the correct permissions to be executed by the motion process.  More details on the configuration can be found in the Motion Docs:

https://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/ConfigFileOptions

Answer (score -2):

I have a simple solution but someone needs to explain how this works. Start motion as root. Add a line to /etc/rc.local 'sudo motion' reboot and most events will work if started as root, on_event_end sudo ...command or script...

Comment: It is not recommended to run a whole daemon as root if it would simply be enough to set the correct permissions for your script.